# How can I force a locked workstation to log off after a timeout?

Tags: windows

I would like to have workstations automatically log-off after a set period of inactivity. There are many solutions to lock a workstation after a timeout and a few hacks to log off a workstation when the user becomes inactive. However, when the workstation is locked but not disconnected, the `query user` command shows 'Active' for the user and those hacks do not work. (https://superuser.com/questions/269574/how-can-i-automatically-log-out-users-from-a-windows-machine?rq=1)

I would like to set a policy that would automatically log a user off after ~5 days of inactivity. Unfortunately this means using logon hours is not feasible as I cannot set certain hours or certain days for this logoff requirement.

The "idle" trigger for task scheduler also seems to not be ideal as any CPU activity blocks it rather than just user activity.

Unfortunately I also cannot justify a third-party utility or cost associated with this configuration.

Comment: I've never seen the output of `quser` ever be active when the screen is locked and no account is logged on. As long as no RDP session or console session is active without screen locked, the status of `quser` should not be active on Windows 10. I've seen on machines with 5 disconnected sessions or even 1 disconnected session used both RDP remotely and at console with a mix. If you put policy to lock screen for user inactivity for 1 hour, then `quser` should get you all disconnected sessions to logoff. I've never seen all sessions locked or disconnected show as active, that sounds weird to me.

Answer (score 1):

One way that can be done is using a  policy group if your are referring to RDP sessions. For example, go to:
LocalComputerPoplicy --> Computer Configuration --> Administrative Templates --> Windows Components --> Remote Desktop Services --> Remote Desktop Session Host --> Session Time Limits. Set values in that policy as you need

Another option is the method described in [this article](https://4sysops.com/archives/automatically-log-off-idle-users-in-windows/). Or you can try [this application](https://www.fortypoundhead.com/showcontent.asp?artid=24173) that is free to use. If you are still using Windows 7, [this old post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/d358382c-e91b-4e91-a1e8-04c53cfd91ce/automatic-logout-after-inactivityidle?forum=w7itprogeneral) can be helpful for your case.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately these will not work. First, these are local logons and not RDP sessions. Second, I cannot use third party apps so Idlelogoff.exe is not possible (even if the link wasn't removed due to malware). Third, winexit.scr won't work on a locked session and messes up screen saver requirements. Fourth, the "when computer is idle" task scheduler item is only when computer is idle and not the user, it doesn't work as expected.